# How to select the debugging mode automating Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, envdte

I have the following code:

```
Process process = instance.Debugger.LocalProcesses.OfType<Process>().Single(p => p.ProcessID == processId);

process.Attach();
```

When I run this the debugger attaches using native code and I want to specify managed code. How can I do it?

I haven't found a way to setup the debugging mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Attach2 method that allows to specify the engine. It is documented on msdn. You'll need to cast to a Process2 before using it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.process2.attach2.aspx

You may also want to wait for the debugger to be running, check out how the Python tools are doing it:

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28475480/

Comment: No problem. Btw you Attacher app looks pretty good, I'll give it a go!

Comment: Good! Comments welcome. I think it is a productivity booster, at least in my company where we develop mainly Prism applications.